# Using Facebook Graph to find a specific post by ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-php-sdk

```
$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/userid/feed?limit=1');
```

so this is working great to retrieve a list of Facebook page posts...

now what if I wanted to retrieve just one specific post by it's ID number? I'm sure this data is out there somewhere, but I am having a heck of a time searching it up.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the **Post ID**, you don't need such complex query. You can query simply for `/POST-ID`-

```
$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/{POST-ID}');
```

[Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=290805814352519_491593307607101)